# How to input a parameter in a custom target with cmake

Tags: makefile, cmake, command-line-arguments

I have a custom target:

```
 add_custom_target(
      create-po
      COMMAND ${MSGINIT} --no-translator -i "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/${PACKAGE}.pot" - "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/po/es.po" -l es_MX.utf8
 )
```

so, is invoked like this:

```
 # make create-po
```

my idea is to change it to something like this:

```
 # make create-po "es"
```

so, any user can create a custom localed po file. I don't know the word exactly for this, but I'd like to add a parameter in the target name..is it posible with cmake? Thanks

Comment: I don't know about the cmake part of this question but make itself cannot take arguments like that as such. It would need to be something like `make create-po POLANG=es` or something like that to work I believe.

Comment: Why not just generate targets with names like `create-po-${lang}` and then run `make create-po-es`? With a bit of imagination, the `-es` part is just like a parameter.

Comment: I like your idea, arrowdodger, but I want any user can create their own PO file. If I follow your idea, the end user must edit configure.ac or Makefile.am to generate the appropiate target.

Comment: I doubt you can do it because cmake can be used with different generators (like visual studio), hence I think you need some more general concept, e.g. environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

After so long time I found this question for the same reason: Can I use CMake to initialize a .po file if I want to add a new translation? I expect to use it only once in a while for my project, so make the build system do it seems more comfortable to me than find out all the required options and paths every time.

I ended up with the following CMake snippet:

```
set(INIT_LANG CACHE STRING "give a locale here to create a target which initializes a related .po file")
IF(INIT_LANG)
  add_custom_target(
    create-po-${INIT_LANG}
    ... # integrate INIT_LANG in your command
  )
ENDIF(INIT_LANG)
```

Then, if you want to initialize a new translation file, call (assuming your build dir in under the project root):

```
# cmake -DINIT_LANG=es_MX.utf8 ..
```

... and you should get a corresponding make target:

```
# make create-po-es_MX.utf8
```

Yes, it's not as straight-forward as the OP's idea/expectation (and mine as well), but users can create new .po files by themselves (of course, this will be documented properly for them in the project ;) ).